# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars, problem with float

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I don't know what the problem is, maybe I used np.asfarray wrong?
It is noted that the error is in line 6.

```
for i in training_data_list:
    all_values = i.split(',') 
    inputs_x = np.asfarray(all_values[1:])
    outputs = n.query(inputs_x)
    print(int(all_values[1]), 'or', int(all_values[2]), '=' ,  float(outputs), '\n')
```

Full Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/7x/q0gw9knx0klf7ngkgvd95wj40000gn/T/ipykernel_62654/1155902910.py in <module>
      3     inputs_x = np.asfarray(all_values[1:])
      4     outputs = n.query(inputs_x)
----> 5     print(int(all_values[1]), 'or', int(all_values[2]), '=' ,  float(outputs), '\n')

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

The result should be:

```
0 OR 0 = 0.0015221568573919875 

1 OR 0 = 0.9999989042032791 

0 OR 1 = 0.9999985457530554 

1 OR 1 = 1.000000835153846
```

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible example, what are `training_data_list`? `n`?

Comment: The full error message does probably contain more than just the line number. Please provide the full traceback (all lines of the error message).

Comment: try `print(outputs)`

Comment: You probably need to apply `float` to each array element:
`outputs = [float(x) for x in n.query(inputs_x)]`
but it's all quite blind, because we do not have access to your data

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/7x/q0gw9knx0klf7ngkgvd95wj40000gn/T/ipykernel_62654/1155902910.py in <module>
      3     inputs_x = np.asfarray(all_values[1:])
      4     outputs = n.query(inputs_x)
----> 5     print(int(all_values[1]), 'or', int(all_values[2]), '=' ,  float(outputs), '\n')

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: ``` training_data = open("dataset/Data_train.csv", 'r')
training_data_list = training_data.readlines()
training_data.close()```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some valid uses of `float`

```
In [18]: float('1.23')
Out[18]: 1.23
In [19]: float(np.array(2.34))
Out[19]: 2.34
In [20]: float(np.array([2.34]))
Out[20]: 2.34
```

and invalid ones:

```
In [21]: float('1.23 2.32')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [21] in <cell line: 1>
    float('1.23 2.32')
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1.23 2.32'

In [22]: float(np.array([1.23, 3.34]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [22] in <cell line: 1>
    float(np.array([1.23, 3.34]))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

`float` is Python function that tries to return **one** float value.

I don't know what `n.query` does or is, but the error suggests that `outputs is a numpy array with more than one element

```
outputs = n.query(inputs_x)
```

Have you examined `outputs`?  What is it - type, shape, dtype, etc?  Does it even need conversion to `floats`.

### edit

Try this print:

```
print(all_values[1], 'or', all_values[2], '=' ,  outputs)
```

It may not be the prettiest, but at least is should work. Or

```
print(f'{all_values[1]} or {all_values[2]} = {outputs}')
```

for example:

```
In [45]: all_values = [0, 2, 3]; outputs = np.array([1.23, 2.12])

In [46]: print(all_values[1], 'or', all_values[2], '=' ,  outputs)
2 or 3 = [1.23 2.12]
In [47]: print(f'{all_values[1]} or {all_values[2]} = {outputs}')
2 or 3 = [1.23 2.12]
```

Once you get some working output, you can go on to worry about fine points of formatting.  Throwing `int()` and `float()` into the display without understanding what you are doing is not going to help.

Comment: outputs This is a neural network run

Comment: What's that supposed to tell me - or you?  I don't know one 'neuroal network' from another.  I'm asking about `outputs`, Python/numpy terms.  Why are you trying to use `float`?  Surely there's some reason, or is this just some sort of hit-or-miss kind of programming?

Comment: I can only say that in the end this program should output such a result:    

0 OR 0 = 0.0015221568573919875

1 OR 0 = 0.9999989042032791

0 OR 1 = 0.9999985457530554

1 OR 1 = 1.000000835153846

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/7x/q0gw9knx0klf7ngkgvd95wj40000gn/T/ipykernel_62654/2767855100.py in <module>
      3     inputs_x = np.asfarray(all_values[1:])                                                                   
           4     outputs = np.asfarray(n.query(inputs_x))
          ----> 5     print(int(all_values[1]), 'or', int(all_values[2]), '=' ,  float(outputs), '\n')

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Read your own comment.  Multiline stuff like this should be added as an edit to the question.

Comment: I edit my question